# product detail from DB unique

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm trying to show the detail of my product from a database, but i only want to show the product I clicked using the button "afficher le detail" right now it shows all app at once. 
Any tips would be appreciated because I'm really lost on this one.
i don't know if i need to modify the index, class.app or product page.

this is what i got on my index.php

```
<?php
    session_start();
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Applications</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
        include ("class.app.php");
            $obj_app = new app();

        include("class.client.php");
            $obj_client = new client();

            $btnajouterpanier=false;

            if(isset($_SESSION['utilisateur'])){
                if($obj_client->validate_login($_SESSION['utilisateur'],$_SESSION['motdepasse'])){
                    echo $obj_client->get_welcome_message($_SESSION['utilisateur']);
                    $btnajouterpanier=true;
                }
            }

            if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST' && $_SERVER["CONTENT_TYPE"] === 'application/json'){
                $data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'),true);
                $resultat = array('ajout' => FALSE);
                $_SESSION['panier'][$_POST($data['id'])]+= 1;
                $resultat['ajout'] = TRUE;
            }

        echo '<form name="frm_cat" action="index.php" method="POST">';
        echo '<select name="lst_cat">';
            $obj_app->get_cat_options();
        echo '</select>';
        echo '<input type="submit" name="btn_cat" value="Filtrer" />';
        echo '</form>';

        if(isset($_POST['lst_cat'])){
            $obj_app->get_app_list($_POST['lst_cat'],$btnajouterpanier);
        }else{
            $obj_app->get_app_list('',$btnajouterpanier);
        }
        ?>
        <script src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="panier.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

this is my class.app.php

```
<?php
class app{
        private $dbh;

        public function __construct(){
            $this->dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=appstore','root','',array(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_OBJ));
        }

        public function get_cat_options(){
            $req = $this->dbh->prepare('SELECT * FROM cat ORDER BY titre');
            $req->execute();
            while($cat = $req->fetch()){
                echo '<option value="'.$cat->id.'">'.$cat->titre.'</option>';
            }
        }

        public function get_app_list($idcat="",$btnajouterpanier=false){
            if ($idcat!=""){
                $reqapp = $this->dbh->prepare("SELECT app.* FROM app JOIN appcat ON app.id=appcat.idapp WHERE appcat.idcat='".$idcat."'");
                }else{
                    $reqapp = $this->dbh->prepare("SELECT app.* FROM app");
                }
                $reqapp->execute();
                while($app = $reqapp->fetch()){
                    echo '<h3>'.$app->nom.'</h3><br/>';
                    echo '<img src="image/'.$app->image.'" /><br/>';
                    echo '<p>'.$app->description.'</p><br/>';
                    echo $app->prix.' $<br/>';
                    echo "<form name='btn_det' method='POST' action='produit.php'><input type='hidden' name='app_detail' value='".$app->id."' /><input type='submit' name='iddetail' value='Afficher le detail' data-id='".$app->id."'/></form>";

                        if($btnajouterpanier){
                            echo '<button type="button" class="btnajouterpanier" data-id="$app->id">Ajouter au panier</button>';
                        }
                    echo '<hr/>';
                }
        }

        public function detail($iddetail){
                $reqdet = $this->dbh->prepare('SELECT * FROM app where id = ?'); 
                $reqdet->execute(array($iddetail));

            while($app = $reqdet->fetch()){
                echo '<h3>'.$app->nom.'</h3><br/>';
                echo '<img src="image/'.$app->image.'" /><br/>';
                echo '<p>'.$app->description.'</p><br/>';
                echo $app->prix.' $<br/>';
            }

        }

}
?>
<script src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="panier.js"></script>
```

and this is my produit.php page

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Document sans nom</title>
</head>

<body>
<?php
        include ("class.app.php");
            $obj_app = new app();



            $obj_app->detail($_POST['iddetail'])

?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need a `where` clause. `$reqdet = $this->dbh->prepare('SELECT * FROM app where id = ?'); $reqdet->execute(array($iddetail));` I'd think

Comment: That should be literal if `$obj_app->detail($_POST['btn_det'])` works. `action='produit.php'` looks like a typo..

Comment: No, now it shows nothing on the product page...

Comment: No error? Is `$_POST['btn_det']` populated?

Comment: **action='produit.php'** isn't a typo i want to change page when i click the button, but it may be a wrong use of the code

Comment: Your other page is called `product.php` though, no?

Comment: i think so itry to send the id when i click but still not sure if i done it well

Comment: no it's produit.php, i'm french so i mainly use french name for the pages

Comment: Okay, I edited the description. The `<form name='btn_det".$app->id."' method='POST' action='produit.php'>` needs an element named `btn_det` which has the value of the ID you want it to select.